# Can't get PHP to work with my Nginx virtual host. Keeps returning "No input file specified"

Tags: php, nginx

I'm trying to get phpmyadmin up and running on my server. Here's the nginx vhost for it:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server.mydomain.net;

    location /phpmyadmin/ {
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/phpmyadmin$fastcgi_script_name;

        include /opt/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params;
        alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
    }

    root /opt/nginx/html/;
}
```

Here's my fastcgi_params file

```
fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
```

I compiled lighthttpd so I could pull out spawn-fcgi. That is now sitting in /usr/local/bin and is accompanied by my php5-cgi launcher which looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/local/bin/spawn-fcgi -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9000 -u www-data -C 2 -f /usr/bin/php5-cgi
```

I run this and can see that it's successfully launched by doing a `ps aux | grep php`.

However, whenever I try to open phpmyadmin, I get the error "No input file specified"

What am I doing wrong? :/

Answer (score 3):

"No input file specified" is the error PHP gives when it cannot find a file at the path it's given. Nginx passes this path in `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/phpmyadmin$fastcgi_script_name;`

Your error is that $fastcgi_script_name; contains the URI, since you're in location `/phpmyadmin/` that means the URI is `/phpmyadmin/whatever.php`. Therefore you're essentially passing `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/whatever.php`.

If you correct your path it should work.

Comment: That fixed it. Cheers.

Comment: Good to know. Could you accept the answer then?